# How can I package up software to build ec2 instances from without using AMI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My company builds "certified" AMIs for us to use. I want to create an EC2 instance from that and install some software and then package that back up to be able to create EC2 instances from this new package.

Ideally, this new package would be AMI from the EC2 instance that I installed the software on, but this isn't an option for me.

Is there another way to achieve something similar? I'm just trying to avoid having to install the same software on every EC2 instance I create.

Thanks!

Comment: This wins the award for clueless policies.  If you are saying that you are allowed to install custom software, there's no benefit whatsoever in preventing you from building your own custom AMIs from the "certified" base AMI.

Comment: Completelt agree!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An AMI image is the only way to "package up" what you have already installed. If you cannot create and use your own custom AMI images, then you must use a sanctioned AMI image, and install what you need on top of that.

However, you can automate that process so you don't have to sign-in to the EC2 instance and install the software manually. You have a few options:

1. Put all your `apt-get install` items in your EC2 instances user data as an init script. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html
2. Use a configuration management tool such as Puppet, Chef, Ansible to configure your EC2 instances after they are launched.

Comment: @Castaglia, Packer will build AMI, which is exactly what topic starter is trying to avoid.

Comment: 3. Use OpsWorks. Same Chef, but native to AWS.

Comment: @SergeyKovalev Packer can also be used to build VirtualBox/VMWare images, Docker images, etc (which can then be imported back to AMIs if/when wanted).  And an AWS AMI [can be exported](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmexport.html), thus allowing the OP to export the base AMI, and use Packer to package up their software in non-AMI formats as needed.

Comment: @Castaglia AMIs cannot be exported. EC2 instances can be exported as a VM, but only if they were previously imported. EC2 instances from stock AMIs cannot be exported.